# Annotations not showing on youtube-nocookie.com

Tags: video, youtube, embed, youtube-iframe-api

is there a way to show annotations on youtube embedded videos with youtube-nocookie.com?

I noticed that when I embed a video in my site with youtube-nocookie.com the annotations don't show, while if I embed the same video with youtube.com the annotations show correctly.

Is there a way? Thanks